# Time between power on and kernel starting

Tags: boot, kernel, bootloader

On my RPi2, I have measured exactly 5 seconds between :

- "I plug the power cord"

and

- "Kernel starting time 0.00s", as displayed on the top left here:

[image]

**Is there a way to optimize this before-kernel-boot-time in config.txt or cmdline.txt?**

I already have set `boot_delay=0`, that saves 1 second boot time, compared to default value `boot_delay=1` (see http://elinux.org/RPiconfig)

Comment: Telling us a bit more about why your are doing this might help us provide you better answers.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I'm using the Pi as an *embedded computer* (RPi not visible for the end user) : I'm looking for as-fast-as-possible boot.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is much to gain by tweaking the config files to speed up the GPU boot strap process. To my knowledge *cmdline.txt* is passed to the kernel only so it will not influence the *pre-kernel-boot-time*. *config.txt* on the other hand is already used during the boot so it at least thinkable that overclocking settings for GPU and RAM frequency might speed up things a little (or just fail horribly).

Other than that it would seem to me that changes to the system would require a rewrite of the different stages of the bootloader ([see here](https://thekandyancode.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/how-the-raspberry-pi-boots-up/)). But whether this would really speed things up or not is questionable and depends on how heavily that code is already optimized and what effort one likes to spend on doing it better...